# ajax search not working after spacebar

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have the below code that search based on first name and last name. Once I press space after first name, then the search result disappears.How to make the search result appear after pressing space. I am calling the ajax function in a textbox for firstname/LastName.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
$('#suggestions').hide();
} else {
 $.post("states.jsp", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
if(data.length >0) {
$('#suggestions').show();
$('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
}
});
}
}
function fill(thisValue) {
$('#inputString').val(thisValue);
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
 }
</script>
```

// States.JSP File

```
    String sql = "SELECT EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID, EMP_FNAME, EMP_LNAME FROM UAP.dbo.UAP_EMPLOYEE     where EMP_FNAME LIKE '%"+name+"%' OR EMP_LNAME LIKE '%"+name+"%';";
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
stm.executeQuery(sql);
ResultSet rs= stm.getResultSet();
while (rs.next ()){

 out.println("<li onclick='fill(\""+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+" " +rs.getString("EMP_LNAME")+"\");'>"+rs.getString("EMP_FNAME")+"  "+rs.getString("EMP_LNAME")+"   </li>");
}}catch(Exception e){
out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `name` in your SQL statement, try trimming all leading and trailing whitespaces in it. That should probably work. As last name and first names are in two different columns. When you hit space. value something like this `John<whitespace>` is being sent to the query. Now obviously in your first name column name must be `John` only, without the whitespace. As query tries to find the name John with trailing white space, it might be failing. Thus your search results are disappearing after you hit space.

Comment: did you find this helpful? Even I am eager to know ;)